# Error: DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must be set to True

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, xgboost

I trained a XGB on a dataset with int, floats, and objects. Now, I want to construct a feature importance using Shap Values. However, I encounter an error that states:

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category.  When
categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must be 
set to `True`
```

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
import shap

model = XGBClassifier()
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ("preprocessing", preprocessing_pipeline),
    ("classifier", model)
])

trained_pipeline = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred_test = trained_pipeline.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]
y_pred_train = trained_pipeline.predict_proba(X_train)[:, 1]

#evaluate model on test set
X_eval = X_test.copy()
X_eval.insert(0, 'TARGET', y_test)
X_eval.insert(1, 'PREDICTION', y_pred_test)
X_eval.insert(2, 'ACCURATE', X_eval["TARGET"] == (X_eval["PREDICTION"] > 0.5))
X_eval = X_eval.reset_index()

#plot feature importance using Shap values
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model)
shap_values = explainer.shap_values(X_eval)
```

Comment: I think, there are some categorical features in your dataset. You need to label encode them. Can you show us your `preprocessing_pipeline` and `model`? And please share the top 10 rows of your data too.